# at job scheduler doesn't work on my Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scheduler, at-utility

I know there are many linux experts here, I wish to get little help with `at` command in Ubuntu.
I have been troubled by `at` command in ubuntu (18.04 and 20.04) for quite a while, but I don't know where I made a mistake. I've tried `at` on three of my Ubuntu systems and it doesn't work on any of them. `at` is very handle and nice job scheduler, I really want to get it to work so that I do not have to manually launch programs in the late night on a shared Ubuntu server. I read many tutorials on `at` command, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/339301/879945) is a very good one.

`at now + 1 minutes -f ~/myscript.sh`, it looks really great and can save me lots of energy. Unfortunately, when `myscript.sh` is extremely simple,then `at now + 1 minutes -f ~/myscript.sh` can run smoothly and I get what I expected. Here is everything I have in `myscript.sh`:

`echo $(date) > ~/Desktop/time.txt`

On top of that, it never worked for me. For example when I change  `myscript.sh` to

```
echo $(date) > ~/Desktop/time.txt
pycharm.sh
```

Basically what `myscript.sh` does it is noting down the time and to open Pycharm IDE. I can run `sh myscript.sh` without `at` , it wroks very well. However, when I run at `at now + 1 minutes -f ~/myscript.sh`, the time is noted down but Pycharm was not never opened (I can see the process in `htop` if Pycharm is open). Also `at now + 1 minutes -f ~/script.sh` does not work with any of my other shell scripts.

Could you please help me understand where I have done wrong and how to make it work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm and other GUI programs need a lot of information from your environment. The `atd` daemon which runs jobs for at does not have access to this environment. You will need to specify it directly.

I recommend running `printenv` redirected to a file in an at job. Then compare that to `printenv` running from a terminal in your GUI session. Find the differences and see if you can set them up the same way at the beginning of your at script.

Comment: Mr Zan, you are right, ````at```` does not seem to have access to all the variables in a normal terminal. I have tried ````source $HOME/.profile```` to, my shell script but it still does not work. DO you know how to add all env variables to ````at````. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89596/400554